# MySQL, group rows in SELECT result

Tags: mysql, select

Is it possible, with a select query, to get something like

```
| firstfield | secondfield | types
  firstvalue   secondvalue   1,2,3
```

Instead of

```
| firstfield | secondfield | type
  firstvalue   secondvalue   1
  firstvalue   secondvalue   2
  firstvalue   secondvalue   3
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select firstfield, secondfield, GROUP_CONCAT(type order by type) as types
from yourtable
group by firstfield, secondfield;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are going to need to look at using group by.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html